# Dark Mode and Windows 10 Remote Desktop Visual Glitches

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, dark-mode

For work, I'm connecting to a Window 10.0.19045 machine using either Microsoft Remote Desktop or Ivanti Pulse Secure Terminal Services Client depending on where I'm connecting from. (Both client machines are also running Windows 10.0.19045.) On all machines, I've picked `Settings: Colors: Select Your Color: Dark`. This produces the desired result on the client machines, but via remote desktop, some of the UI elements don't get dark backgrounds, resulting in light text and graphics over light backgrounds. (Obviously, I redacted a lot.)

I'm not an admin on any of these boxes, sadly. Are there any settings I can change to fix this? Are there any settings I can ask the people who are admins to try?

[image]

Comment: It might be covered in RDP connection settings > Experience: there are a couple similar features that are dependent on connection quality (If you have it on detect automatically, it can disable certain features that could cause what you're seeing). Another place to check is under Advanced System Settings (requires admin) > Performance > Visual Effects on the clients. Could also be related to graphics drivers, etc, but looks more like a low connection quality thing to me, based on the screenshot